# Pandas: Count the occurence of words (from another dataframe), and output the count and matched words

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (df) with a column containing sentences. I have a second dataframe (df2) with a column containing words. Per row in df, I want to count how many times a word from df2 occurs in the sentence, and if it does occur output the count into a new column, and output the matched words into a new column.

I have worked out how to do the counts, but I can't work out how to output the matched words - see the df_desiredoutput dataframe for what I want. thanks in advance.

Here is some dummy code

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'sentence': ['Hello how are you', 'It is nice outside today', 'I need to water the plants', 'I need to cook dinner', 'See you tommorow']})
print(df)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'words': ['hello', 'you', 'plants', 'need', 'tommorow']})
print(df2)

df["count"] = df["sentence"].str.count('|'.join(df2['words']), re.I)
print(df)

df_desiredoutput = pd.DataFrame({'sentence': ['Hello, how are you?', 'It is nice outside today', 'I need to water the plants', 'I need to cook dinner', 'See you tommorow'],
                          'count': ['2', '0', '2', '1', '2'],
                          'match': ['hello; you', '', 'need; plants', 'need', 'you; tomorrow']})
print(df_desiredoutput)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
pat = '|'.join(df2['words'])
df["count"] = df["sentence"].str.count(pat, re.I)
df["match"] = df["sentence"].str.findall(pat, re.I).str.join('; ')
print(df)
                     sentence  count          match
0           Hello how are you      2     Hello; you
1    It is nice outside today      0               
2  I need to water the plants      2   need; plants
3       I need to cook dinner      1           need
4            See you tommorow      2  you; tommorow
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you jezrael. Worked perfect. I thought I was close to being on the right track but didn't think to use str.findall.